# ms access template where to find the vb code

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm very new to this ms access 2007. I have a copy of a charitable contribution template 
charitablecontributions.accdb. 
I would like to know where I can find the code of it?

I opened it by holding down the shift button and double click on it and it will open to a normal ms access where you can modify the table and so.

But when I just click the file: charitablecontributions.accdb it will open to a formular view where the ribbon bars are gone. 
I wanted to know how, how is it possible to have this formular view? Because I have a Test.mdb from 2003 and I also would like it to be open like the formular view of charitablecontributions.accdb.

I'll appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: There is no code in the Charitable Contributions ACCDB. It is entirely driven by embedded macros, which were first introduced in A2007 as part of MS's effort to avoid arbitrary code execution (so you wouldn't have to trust the code in a database). In A2010, these embedded macros become even more important, being extended such that they can be embedded in tables (replicating what triggers do in server DBs), and are important drivers of integration with Sharepoint, which will allow very easy porting to the web (hosted on Sharepoint).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

My prior answer was completely and totally wrong. I misread the question, and apologize. (This is the downside of hitting these sites before my morning caffeine!)

Not all Access databases will have code. However, you don't need code to get your databases to display this behavior.

1. Open the database you wish to create a startup form for in Microsoft Access.
2. Click the Microsoft Office button in the upper left of the Access window.
3. Click the "Current Database" option on the left side of the Options window that comes up.
4. Select the form you wish to use at startup from the "Display Form" box.
5. Scroll down, and uncheck the following boxes:

   - "Display Navigation Pane" This turns off the left-hand bar.
   - "Allow Full Menus"
   - "Allow Default Shortcut Menus"
   - "Allow Built-In Toolbars"

Of course, all this is predicated on having a form for startup. Also, once you do this, you will need to start up the database holding down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key to make changes to it.

Comment: that also works in ms access 2007. I was in the design mode and try to open the macro vb code by pressing alt F11. And a window for the VB was shown but there was no code inside.
wondering where I can find this.
thanks for checking later John

Comment: Hi John it seems I can't find this Current Database, do I need to open an .mdb file format database for this? or just the Microsoft office button?